# formula for getting the normlized X and Y values of a given degrees from a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, trigonometry

I have a number  which we'll call α in degrees that represent the angle of a linear function with the X axis. for example when α is 0 the linear function is on the X axis , when α is 360 the linear function is on the X axis.
when α is 90 the linear function is on the Y axis. and so on.
I want to get from the linear function

```
y = αx
```

the X of y = 1, and the Y of x = 1. 
and I am not sure how can I do that.
can anyone post a quick forumla for calc such a thing? does it have a name ?
I know trigo may be needed to transfer degrees for a slope that represent the value of y for X = 1.

Comment: When $\alpha =90°$, it doesn't necessarily mean that the linear function is on the y-Axis. It rather shows that it is **parallel** to the y-axis

Comment: Is $\alpha$ given, or do you get the function and have to calculate it?

Comment: alpha is given.

Comment: What's the problem then? You would have: $$\text{X of y=1}=\frac{1}{\alpha}$$ and $$\text{Y of x=1}=\alpha$$ Or am I missing something?

Comment: Alpha is in degrees how do I transfer that to a slope (Y value for X = 1) ?

Comment: Oh! If the inclination degree is $\alpha$, then the slope of the function is $\arctan (\alpha)$

Comment: There's a nice explanation here: https://math.tutorvista.com/geometry/angle-of-inclination.html

Comment: So it's simply X=1/atan(alpha) Y=atan(alpha) ? Nice and simple solution. Thank you. Can you make an answer on that so I could mark it as solved ?

Comment: Oh thanks! PS: I've just noticed there's something wrong I said: the slope of the function equals $\tan (\alpha)$ and not $\arctan(\alpha)$ Srry

Comment: Although wait, are you dealing with the function $y=mx$ with $m=\text{slope}$ and inclination angle $=\alpha$? Or is it the function $y=\alpha x$?

Comment: Im dealing with the first one. From what I understand I can do arctan to my inclination angle alpha to get the slope (the m of the linear function forumla ). Note that it's not really an inclination angle since when alpha =360 it should be the same as alpha=0 but I guess if alpha > 180 i can take the angle of the linear function with minus X and use it as alpha basically alpha-180 , learned math in another language so sorry for the general terms.

Comment: just for curiosity, in which language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:**

> If $\alpha$ is the inclination angle of a linear function, then the slope of the function is $\arctan \alpha$

Proof

Let $\Delta ABC$ be the slope triangle of the function, with $[AB]$ lying on the x-axis. Denote by $m$ the slope of the function and by $\alpha$ the angle of the linear function with the x-axis. Since $\angle CBA=90°$, we can tell $$\tan(\angle BAC)=\tan(\alpha)=\frac{BC}{AB}=m$$

[image]

Let then simply $$X=\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}$$ and $$Y=\tan(\alpha)$$